How to reliably find synonyms within a corpus of data?
I'm working on a project where I need to identify synonyms for terms across a specific corpus of product data. The data is a list of products, and I'm trying to find similar terms that appear repeatedly in the titles, descriptions and other fields. For example searching for "baby" should return "newborn", "toddler", "infant" if they're available in the corpus.
I've experimented with some pre-trained embeddings in gensim, specifically the "glove-wiki-gigaword-100" model. This got me some reasonable results, but it missed a few obvious synonyms and included some unrelated terms as well. I also tried using Word2Vec, but my corpus of products is too small to train a high-quality custom model, so it didn't yield very useful results either.
Here's a simplified version of my most successful code:
from gensim.downloader import load as gensim_load
from typing import List, Set, Dict
from .models import AlgoProduct

def get_corpus_words(products: List[AlgoProduct]) -> Set[str]:
    corpus_words = set()
    for p in products:
        corpus_words.add(p.object.lower())
        corpus_words.update([m.lower() for m in p.words_of_interest])
    return corpus_words

def load_pretrained_model():
    model = gensim_load("glove-wiki-gigaword-100")
    return model

def get_similar_words(model, word: str, corpus_words: Set[str], topn: int = 10) -> Set[str]:
    similar_words = set()
    try:
        top_similar = model.most_similar(word.lower(), topn=topn)
        for similar_word, similarity in top_similar:
            if similar_word in corpus_words:
                similar_words.add(similar_word)
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return similar_words

def get_synonyms(products: List[AlgoProduct]) -> Dict[str, Set[str]]:
    synonyms: Dict[str, Set[str]] = {}
    corpus_words = get_corpus_words(products)
    model = load_pretrained_model()

    for word in corpus_words:
        synonyms[word] = get_similar_words(model, word, corpus_words)

    return synonyms

This function builds a dictionary with each term in the corpus mapped to its synonyms. But the results are inconsistent—many entries have empty sets or miss expected synonyms:
{'baby': {'girl', 'toddler', 'newborn'}, 'bibs': set(), 'shoes': {'boots'}, 'newborn': {'baby', 'toddler'}, ... }

In some of my previous iterations, I was getting overly broad matches or just odd, unrelated terms:
{'Nest': [], 'baby': ['for', 'toddler', 'boots', 'sleeping', 'strap'], 'nappy': ['blanket', 'hipseat', 'shoes'], ...}

The current iteration is okay, depending on the product list it can get pretty close, but I am looking for ways to further optimize and improve the reliability. I am certain that this is not the most optimal approach.
To summarize, I basically need to find synonyms in my own corpus of data, in theory I can just find all synonyms and then figure out what appears in my corpus, but that seems relatively inefficient and I doubt it would be as reliable.

Models like word2vec and GloVe encode semantic meaning of words based on their contextual usage.  Words like "newborn", "toddler", and "infant" all have similar contextual usage, but the words "girl" and "boy" will also have similar contextual usage.  So to word2vec and GloVe, they ARE very similar and thereby are synonyms, at least in terms of their semantic usage.
